# How to open a file

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project I am trying to open a file. I am storing all the path of the file name along with extensions like .exe,.doc,.xml,etc.....in my database. I am fetching that path and trying to open it.In this I like to open it as a popup window to ask like OPEN,SAVE,CANCEL . Can any one help me to solve this problem. Here is the code:

```
private void OpenMyFile()
{
    string path = GetPath() + ViewState["fileopen"];
    FileInfo file = new FileInfo(ViewState["fileopen"].ToString());
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"server=servername;database=DBNAME;uid=ID;pwd=PWD;max pool size=250;Connect Timeout=0");
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from filetypemaster where extension='" + file.Extension + "'", con);
    myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();


    if (myReader.Read())
    {
        Response.ContentType =(String)myReader["CONTENT_TYPE"];
        myReader.Close();

    }
    else
    {
        myReader.Close();
        Message("Cannot open selected file");
        return;
    }

    Response.WriteFile(path);
    Response.End();

    con.Close();
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you specifically need help with?

Comment: Need some more info and tags... I see a ViewState, is this ASP.NET? And do you want that Dialog server-side or on the client?

Comment: I like to open a file available in this path with all extension.

Comment: Just redirect the user to the file. It has to be shared

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're asking, in a round about way, is how to get the file save dialog to show on the client?

You need to set the content disposition header. See here: http://www.jtricks.com/bits/content_disposition.html which might help.

Simon